# Number of ways a page can be chosen so that sum of the digits is 9

Tags: combinatorics

A book contains 1000 pages.Number of ways a page can be chosen so that sum of the digits is 9;is equal to $\lambda$,then the value of $\frac{\lambda}{11}$ is

$(A)2\hspace{1cm}(B)4\hspace{1cm}(C)5\hspace{1cm}(D)6\hspace{1cm}(E)7$

I am going to count them manually,but the process is tedious.Can someone tell me an elegant of counting?Please help....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) approach, the number of ways to distribute $9$ balls over $3$ bins is found to be $\binom{9+3-1}2=\binom{11}2=\frac{11\cdot10}{2}$, so the correct answer is (C).

Comment: How did you get $\binom{11}3=55$ it should be $\frac{11*10*9}{3*2}=165$?

Comment: @SE318: Where did I get $\binom{11}3=55$?

Comment: $\frac{11*10}2=55\neq\binom{11}3$.

Comment: Granted, I agree with your final answer, but your method seems flawed?

Comment: Ahh, so I think what you want is 3 multi choose 9, which is $\binom{11}{9}=\binom{11}2=55.$

Comment: @SE318: Sorry, I misunderstood your earlier comment. You're right, and I've corrected the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting property of the number 9(this also works for three) that a number is divisible by 9 if and only if the sum of the digits is also divisible by 9. This, the only candidates for numbers whose digits add up to 9 are numbers that are divisible by 9. It ends up that there are 111 numbers divisible by 9 between 1 and 100, but for many of them the digits add to things like 18 or 27. They cannot add to anything greater than 27 though as we are only looking at numbers with three or less digits(we don't care about 1000). So which ones add up to 9 rather than 18 or 27? Well first if we deal with 27, the only way to get that is 999 so there are 110 left to consider. For two digit numbers, 99 is the only one that adds to 18. For numbers from 100 to 200, there is 189 and 198. For 200 to 300 there is 279, 288, 297. For 300 to 400, there is 369, 378, 387, 396. 400 to 500 has 459 468 477 486 497. Next there is 549, 558, 567, 576, 585, 594. This pattern will continue all the way up so there are 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55 ways to have a number divisible by 9 and add up to 18. Thus there are 111-55-1=55 giving us the answer of c.